# Yank text between marks including last character

Tags: vim

I use the following to yank text from mark `a` up to mark `b` in register `r` :

```
 `a"ry`b
```

It excludes the character on the position of mark `b`.
Example :

```
1234500000
^   ^
a   b
```

I get `1234` in register `r`.

I would like to **include** the character at mark `b` position when I yank.
So I would like to get `12345` in register `r`.

**How would I do it ?** (I would like to avoid positioning `b` to the next 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would probably be to visually select the region before doing the yank.

```
`av`b"ry
```

---

The selection setting should also be set to inclusive. (`set selection?` should return `selection=inclusive` (which is the default)). If it is set to exclusive you would need to move the cursor the left one after selecting the visual section.

```
`av`bl"ry
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not select the character at mark b position. I just have to add l (move right) after the mark b. Please change your answer and I accept it.

Comment: @FZed Whats the value of `set selection?` It should be inclusive (which is the default).

Comment: set selection is exclusive in my configuration. Thanks a lot @FDinoff.

Answer (score 6):

Another easy way is to just add `v` right after `y`, no setting or Visual mode selection necessary.

```
`a"ryv`b
```

`` y`b `` yanks to mark b *excluding* the character under mark b, whereas `` yv`b `` yanks to mark b *including* the character under it.

See `:h o_v` for more info.